# Unable to send an email using javamailsender in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

I am creating a registration form using spring mvc in which email is one of the fields, once user is filled the details and click on register button , I would like to send an email to the given user email address with a random otp.

application context as well as dispatcher xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Provide support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.uday" />

    <!--Provide support for conversion, formatting and validation -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />



    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/page/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"></property>
        <property name="username" value="hr"></property>
        <property name="password" value="umashetti123"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>Login_Detailshbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="checkWriteOperation">false</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="d" class="com.uday.Login_DetailsDao">
        <constructor-arg ref="mysessionFactory" />
    </bean>

      <!-- SET default mail properties -->
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
        <property name="port" value="587"/>
        <property name="username" value="example@gmail.com"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.lang.Exception">Error</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:view-controller path="/WEB-INF/page/"
        view-name="login.jsp" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"
        location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926" />


</beans>
```

Controller class

```
package com.uday;



import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;





@Controller
public class ControllerSignUp_Login {

    private final Login_DetailsDao dao;
    private Login_Details ld = new Login_Details();
    private String OtpMailed = "";
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;


    public ControllerSignUp_Login(Login_DetailsDao login_DetailsDao,JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.dao = login_DetailsDao;
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    @Transactional
    public String diaplay(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("pass") String pass,Model m) {
        if(dao.isLogoinSuccessfull(name , pass)) {
            m.addAttribute("message", "Hello "+name+" You are successfully logged in");
            return "Success";
        }
        else {
            m.addAttribute("message", "Cannot validate given details.Please try again");
            return "login";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/SignUp")
    public String redirect() {
        System.out.println("ControllerSignUp_Login.display()");
        return "signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String display() {
        System.out.println("ControllerSignUp_Login.display()");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/updateDetails")
    @Transactional
    public String display(HttpServletRequest req , Model M) {
        String firstName=req.getParameter("firstName");  
        String lastName=req.getParameter("lastName"); 
        String mobileNo=req.getParameter("mobileNo");  
        String address=req.getParameter("address");  
        String email=req.getParameter("email");  
        String password=req.getParameter("password");       
        if(checkLength(firstName)  && checkLength(lastName) && checkLength(mobileNo) && checkLength(address) && checkLength(email) &&  checkLength(password)) {

            ld.setFirstName(firstName);
            ld.setLastName(lastName);
            ld.setEmail(email);
            ld.setAddress(address);
            ld.setMobileNo(mobileNo);
            ld.setPassword(password);
//          dao.saveEmployee(ld);
//          M.addAttribute("message", "SignUp Successfull !! Thank You");
//          M.addAttribute("displayLogin", true);
            doSendEmail(email);     
            return "ValidationPage";
        }
        else {
            M.addAttribute("message","SignUp Failed !! All details are mandatory.");
            return "signup";


        }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/Home")
    public String displayy() {
        return "Home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String display1() {
        return "login";
    }

    public boolean checkLength(String s) {
        if(s != null && s.length() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping("/submitToDB")
    public String submitToDataBase(HttpServletRequest req , Model M) {
        String otp = req.getParameter("otp");
        if(OtpMailed.equals(otp)) {
            dao.saveEmployee(ld);
            M.addAttribute("message", "SignUp Successfull !! Thank You");
            M.addAttribute("displayLogin", true);
            return "Success";
        }
        else {
            M.addAttribute("message","OTP Authorization failed");
            return "signup";
        }

    }


    @RequestMapping("/validate")
    public String  validateOtp() {
        return "Success";   
    }

    public String generateOtp() {
        String otp = "";
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
            Double d = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
            int value = d.intValue();
            if(value  == 10) {
                otp = otp+1;
            }
            else {
                otp = otp+value;
            }
        }
        return otp;

    }
    public void doSendEmail(String mail) {
         String recipientAddress = mail;
         String subject = "One Time Verification <Uday>";
         String otpGenerated = generateOtp();
         this.OtpMailed = otpGenerated;
         String message = "Please use this OTP "+otpGenerated+ "to signup. ";

         SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();
         email.setTo(recipientAddress);
         email.setSubject(subject);
         email.setText(message);
         mailSender.send(email);

    }

}
```

getting below exception on executing mailsender.send(email) method

logs

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\lib\javamail.providers (The system cannot find the file specified)
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\lib\javamail.address.map (The system cannot find the file specified)
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP p78sm5939377pfa.97 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587

EHLO TASL-umashetti
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [183.82.100.83]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<umashetti@TASL-umashetti>
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. p78sm5939377pfa.97 - gsmtp
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. p78sm5939377pfa.97 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:959)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:464)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:322)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:311)
    at com.uday.ControllerSignUp_Login.doSendEmail(ControllerSignUp_Login.java:160)
    at com.uday.ControllerSignUp_Login.display(ControllerSignUp_Login.java:82)
    at com.uday.ControllerSignUp_Login$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d455b738.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.uday.ControllerSignUp_Login$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$de92940a.display(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection p78sm5939377pfa.97 - gsmtp
```

I have tried changing the port to 25 and 465 but no use

[image]

Comment: try adding `<prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>` under `javaMailProperties` in dispatcher xml

Comment: @sachinrai gettting below exception    DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
DEBUG SMTP: exception reading response: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Comment: can you share your pom.xml or build file, I suspect you missed mail and activation jar, ref: https://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-email-using-java-mail-api-through-gmail-server

Comment: @dkb added jars pic

Comment: can you add this property `"mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"`

Comment: @dkb It is already there!!

Comment: Hmm, incase if you are not able to solve using plain java, give https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html a try

Comment: check for this too: `"mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable","true"`, i think this is missing, check logs `trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false`

Comment: I would suggest to use latest java mail lib: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/

Comment: sorry didnt see you are using explicit `starttls`. Please remove the `<prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>`  from dispatcher xml. your configuration seems fine. However, please note that the password for your account should not be an ordinary password, but an application password generated for your google account. Please follow [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) for setting Google App password and use in your code.

Comment: @sachinrai Thank you for the help !! its working now once I use app password instead of original password but I have used SMTPTransport to send instead javamail sender

Comment: Note that you're using a very, very, very old version of JavaMail.  The current version is [1.6.3](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/javamail/).